# Split string by non-alphabetic characters

Tags: javascript, string

I want to split a string with all non-alphabetic characters as delimiters.

For example, I want to split this string

```
"hello1 twenty-three / nine.bye"
```

into

```
["hello","","twenty","three","","","nine","bye"]
```

I've tried this

```
text.split(/\[A-Za-z]+/)
```

but it isn't working.

How do I split a string by non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: Since you're wanting to match sequential letters, why not use `.match()`? `text.match(/[A-Za-z]+/g)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the not a match atom: `[^`.  Try the following

```
text.split(/[^A-Za-z]/)
```

Comment: You can shorten ``/[^A-Za-z]/`` to ``/[^a-z]/i``. The ``i`` makes the regexp case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the inital backslash breaking your `[]`? What about `text.split(/[^A-Za-z]+/)`?

```
"asdsd22sdsdd".split(/[^A-Za-z]/)
["asdsd", "", "sdsdd"]
```